# How to add a GUI panel and a DrawPanel within one frame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I want two Panels to be added here within one frame, I want some buttons and text fields on the right side there to edit the drawing panel class but I can't figure out how to add GUI components to `panel2`. Whenever I try to add GUI components to `panel2`, it just doesn't work how it would work normally and I don't understand why.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("WaferMap");
        frame.setSize(1286, 829);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        DrawingPanel panel1 = new DrawingPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

        frame.add(panel1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1080, 800));

        final JButton button = new JButton();

        panel2.add(button, BorderLayout.EAST);
        button.setBounds(50,50,100,50);
        frame.add(panel2, BorderLayout.EAST);
        panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 800));
    }
}
```

This is the main, I have another class called `drawingPanel` with a `paintComponent` in it.

Comment: *Whenever I try to add GUI components to panel2, it just doesn't work* - where? I don't see any code where you add a component to the panel. There is no trick you just use the add(…)` method. The trick is using the appropriate layout manager to position the components.  Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). You can download the demo code of each layout manager and play with the code so yo understand how it works.

Comment: If you need more help post a proper [mre] showing the code you tested.

Comment: I tried adding "final JButton button = new JButton();
  panel2.add(button, BorderLayout.EAST);" but it doesn't allow me to edit the size of the button using setBounds for some reason.

Comment: Okay I edited it with what I tried to add in

Comment: Did you read the tutorial and download the working code to see what is different?

Comment: I'll do that, thanks @camickr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't use setPreferredSize(). It is the job of the layout manager to calculate the preferred size of the panel based on the rules of the layout manager and the preferred size of the components added to the panel.
2. Don't use setSize(). Instead use pack(). The frame will be sized based on the preferred size of all components added to the frame.
3. The real problem is that by default a component has a size of (0. 0) so there is nothing to paint. It is the job of the layout manager to give the component a size/location to the component. The problem is that you made the frame visible before you added the components to the panel, so the layout manager was never invoked. So the solution is that the `pack()` and `setVisible(true)` statements should be invoked AFTER all components have been added to the frame.

Note, the tutorial also has a section on `Custom Painting` that you should be reading so you implement the painting properly to make sure your `DrawingPanel` has a preferred size.

Comment: I used setPreferredSize() because I wanted the layout on my window to be fixed as it is. I wanted the paint component to be that set size and same with the GUI.

Comment: Again, did you read the tutorial? Each component should determine its own preferred size. The tutorial shows you how to do this.